# Show $\frac{1}{\sum_{1}^{n}a^2}\leq \frac{n}{\left ( \sum_{1}^{n}a \right )^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to show that $$\frac{1}{\sum_{1}^{n}a^2}\leq \frac{n}{\left ( \sum_{1}^{n}a \right )^2}$$

Until now, I only have $$\left (\sum_{1}^{n}a  \right )^2\leq \left (\sum_{1}^{n}a^2 \right )n$$

Please, any idea on how to procede?

Comment: From what you have, divide by something positive to arrive at the desired result

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to $\tfrac1n\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\ge\left(\tfrac1n\sum_ia_i\right)^2$, i.e. that the mean of $a^2$ is at least the squared mean of $a$, note the difference is $a$'s variance.

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward from Cauchy Schwarz inequality:
$$(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)(1^2+1^2+...+1^2) \ge (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2$$